# How to find a unit normal vector to the given curve?

Tags: vector-analysis

Find the unit normal vector to the curve $r(t) = (3\sin t)i + (3\cos t)j + 4t k$ at point $( \pi /2, 0,1)$.

The tangent vector of this curve is $(3 \cos t)i -(3 \sin t)j + 4k$ and unit normal vector should be perpendicular to this vector at given point.
But I couldn't get the final answer. How to find unit normal vector at the given point$?$

Comment: This point is not on the curve?

Comment: This point is on the curve. I couldn't find any value of $t$  for this point

Comment: Therefore it is not on the curve?

Comment: So, there's no solution?

Comment: If the point is on the curve one can find the value of t as 1/4 of the k coefficient. Then use the formula you mentioned for a correct answer. But this point is not on the curve, so the normal to the curve cannot be found.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that your point is not on the curve, so it does not make sense to compute the unit normal at that point. Anyway, here is a general process to find the unit normal.

First of all you should parametrize your curve by arclength, which is given by
\begin{align}
s(t) & = \int_0^t \lVert r'(x) \rVert\,dx \\
& = 5t.
\end{align}
As a function of $s$, $r$ can be rewritten as $r(s) = \left(3\sin \frac{s}{5},3\cos \frac{s}{5}, \frac{4}{5}s\right)$. The unit tangent is then
$$T(s) = \frac{1}{\lVert \frac{dr}{ds}\rVert}\frac{dr}{ds} = \left(\frac{3}{5}\cos \frac{s}{5}, -\frac{3}{5}\sin \frac{s}{5}, \frac{4}{5} \right).$$
The unit normal is just given by the renormalized derivative of the tangent vector:
$$N(s)=\frac{T'(s)}{\lVert T'(s)\rVert} = \left(-\sin \frac{s}{5},-\cos \frac{s}{5}, 0\right). $$